# Make div fill remaining cell space, display table not working (JsFiddle attached),

Tags: html, css-tables

I have a popup window with a table inside, a row with and 2 divs.

I need the bottom div to take the remaining height.

The offending div is

```
<div id="overview">
```

It overflows the cell

Is there anyway to have this div take up the remaining height without fixing it, as this popup window will change size

[**JsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp2EP/22/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css :

CSS

```
#overview {
  height:auto;
}

.CSSTableGeneratorRound {
  height:auto;
}
```

[My CodePen](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/wEhku)

Comment: Woah thanks, however i really needed the height of the main box to remain the same, and to have the #overview div vertically scroll, sorry my question may have been a little too vague.

Comment: You have to replace "auto" by "fixed size". example #overview {height:150px;} and .CSSTableGeneratorRound{height:500px;}

Comment: I was trying to get around fixing the height of #overview, but i guess there is no way around it, without using some javascript. Anyway thanks for your help